# How do we stop the re-rendering of A and B in React?

Tags: reactjs, rendering

[image]

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect, useCallback } from "react";

export const Root = () => {
  const [items, setItems] = useState(["A", "B"]);

  const _onClick = useCallback( item => {
    return () =>alert(item);
  },[]);
  return (
    <>
      <button onClick={() => setItems(["A", "B", "C"])}>Button</button>
      {items.map((item, index) => (
        <Item key={index} item={item} onClick={_onClick(item)} />
      ))}
    </>
  );
};

const Item = React.memo(({ item, onClick }) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("Item: ", item);
  });
  return <button onClick={onClick}>{item}</button>;
});
```

How do we stop the re-rendering of A and B?
The result I want is to be a memo on the console when the button is pressed and "Item: C".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `onClick` of `<Item/>` is new every time it is rendered, it will cause A and B to re-render.

You can use `React.memo` second parameter to check, for example:

```
const Item = React.memo(({ item, onClick }) => {
    // ...
    return <button onClick={onClick}>{item}</button>;
}, (prevProps, nextProps) => {
    console.log(Object.is(prevProps.onClick, nextProps.onClick)); // console: false
});
```

More see [doc](https://zh-hant.reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactmemo).

---

In your code, `_onClick(item)` will return new callback every render.

```
<Item key={index} item={item} onClick={_onClick(item)} />
```

You can change `_onClick` to this:

```
const _onClick = useCallback(item => alert(item), []);
```

Next, pass _onClick to Item, and change how button's onClick is executed.

```
<Item key={index} item={item} onClick={_onClick} />

//...

<button onClick={() => onClick(item)}>{item}</button>
```

---

The full code is as follows:

```
import React, { useCallback, useState } from 'react';

export const Root = () => {
    const [items, setItems] = useState(['A', 'B']);

    const _onClick = useCallback(item => alert(item), []);
    return (
        <>
            <button onClick={() => setItems(['A', 'B', 'C'])}>Button</button>
            {items.map((item, index) => (
                <Item key={index} item={item} onClick={_onClick} />
            ))}
        </>
    );
};

const Item = React.memo(({ item, onClick }) => {
    useEffect(() => {
        console.log("Item: ", item);
    });
    return <button onClick={() => onClick(item)}>{item}</button>;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You were calling `_onClick` from the wrong place. Rather than calling on the `Item` component, you should call on the button's `onClick` event.

Check these working [Code Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/youthful-wilbur-67cwe).